# Have dataframe by pandas with columns: price, soldPrice, ProductId, and typeTransaction(sell/return). How could calculate Profit take into returns?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate profit but I can not comprehend how could to do 
it.I tried to group by 
 two columns but how to substruct one to another?

```
df[df.groupby(['productId','typeTransaction']).size().reset_index()]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nMAs.png)

Comment: You don't want returns to be included in profits, correct? Meaning a return is $0 profit?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'price': [1200, 1500, 2000, 3000],
    'soldPrice': [1800, 2500, 2300, 5000],
    'typeTransaction': ['sell', 'return', 'return', 'sell']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['profit'] = np.where(df['typeTransaction'] == 'sell', df['soldPrice'] - df['price'], 0)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   price  soldPrice typeTransaction  profit
0   1200       1800            sell     600
1   1500       2500          return       0
2   2000       2300          return       0
3   3000       5000            sell    2000
```